# Apache: point VirtualHost dynamic domains and subdomains to different folders

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Currently I have 2 VirtualHosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName *.*.comp1.office1.lan
 VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-4/%-5/
 UseCanonicalName Off
 <Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName *.comp1.office1.lan
 VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-4/
 UseCanonicalName Off
 <Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Domains like **folder.site.comp1.office1.lan** resolvs correct (`/var/www/site/folder/`).
But on requesting **site.comp1.office1.lan** I recive 404 error.

And apache logs this line:

```
[time...] [error] [client my.ip.there] File does not exist: /var/www/site/_
```

If I change loading order of VirtualHosts (second one loads before first one) than **site.comp1.office1.lan** works god but the problem with 404 respond goes to **folder.site.comp1.office1.lan**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not normally use wildcards in the ServerName entry for a vhost, you would normally put these in a ServerAlias directive instead. Try for example

```
ServerName comp1.office.lan
ServerAlias *.*.comp1.office.lan
...
```

You may have to configure ServerName so that they are all different and have the vhost names match the ServerAlias.